# Pretty Print is not working in chrome console for production build app.js files

Tags: javascript, extjs, build, console, pretty-print

Pretty Print is not working in chrome console for production app.js files

I am using production build and getting dome error :

**Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'b' has already been declared**

My dev build is working fine, in production build I am not able to get the problem as my pritty print is not working.

Screenshots.

[image: Chome Console]

It is working for other builds but not for this specific apps.(note : This app consist two more apps, though taht not should be an issue.)

I have gone through other answers but none of them are use full for me. Any help will great.

Comment: Please try to do a "test" environment build. This will be the same as a production build, but will come pretty printed ;)

Comment: @Dinkheller ya I have tried with the testing build and test build is working fine. I can load the app and things are working smoothly. thanks

Comment: Please share more code and the build options you are using. Do you prefer const, let over var? Is b an uglified variable? Looks so for me. You can try to use var instead of const. This can be seen as a workaround.

Comment: BTW @David the URL being used in the screenshot can be read easily by zooming in.